# Выделение памяти под map

Tags: c++

Создаю map так:

```
map<__int64,__int64> vals;
```

В данном случае, количество элементов map неизвестно. Как можно заранее выделить память под эти элементы? Просто может случиться так, что памяти не хватит, охото это сразу увидеть, а не спустя какое-то время.

Comment: Ну, по логике, использовать свой аллокатор, который сразу заберет нужный кусок памяти, а потом будет из него выделять по запросу нужные кусочки...

Comment: В случае обычного map ноды хранятся в дереве, поэтому, пока не известны значения нод, построить дерево немного напряжно. Но в  бусте есть мапа с подходящими свойстами - [flat_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html). Смотреть на reserve. В любом случае, выделить место под неизвестное кол-во элементов в общем случае нельзя.

Comment: а если проверять на обычном динамическом массиве?выделить память, если выделяется, то удалить